# relation of difference between Perron-Frobenius eigenvalues of two matrices with the operator norm of their difference

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have two non-negative matrices A and B and ∥A−B∥ (operator norm) is very small. What can we say about the absolute value of the difference between the PF eigenvalues of A and B ? Are there any literature on this ? Thanks.

Comment: Bhatia's Matrix Analysis has a lot of eigenvalue matrix inequalities, but nothing pertaining specifically to this situation, I believe.

Comment: Web search using keywords "Perron Frobenius eigenvalue matrix perturbation" yields interesting answers, for example ( https://www.kth.se/social/upload/537a684cf2765444135e67d6/lec8_2014_4.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You may apply the standard perturbation analysis for general matrices like:

$\textbf{Theorem}$. Let $\lambda$ be a simple eigenvalue of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n×n}$ with normalized
right and left eigenvectors $x$ and $y$, respectively. Let $E \in \mathcal{B}(0)$ be a perturbation of $A$, where $\mathcal{B}(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n×n}$ is a sufficiently small open neighborhood of the origin. Then there exist analytic functions $f_\lambda : \mathcal{B}(0) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f_x : \mathcal{B}(0) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ so that $λ = f_\lambda(0)$, $x = f_x(0)$, and $\hat{λ} = f_\lambda(E)$ is an eigenvalue of $A + E$ with
eigenvector $\hat{x} = f_x(E)$. Moreover we have the expansions $$\hat{λ} = \lambda + \frac{y^HEx}{y^Hx} + O(\|E\|^2)\tag{1}$$

Equation (1) can be transformed to
$$|\lambda - \hat{\lambda}| = \frac{|y^HEx|}{|y^Hx|} + O(\|E\|^2) \leq \frac{\|E\|_2}{|y^Hx|}+ O(\|E\|^2)$$

The term $O(\|E\|^2)$ can be removed as in the Bauer-Fike theorem:
$$|\lambda - \hat{\lambda}| \leq n\frac{\|E\|_2}{|y^Hx|}$$

If $A > 0$, $B > 0$ are positive matrices, then by the Perror-Frobenius theorem these maximal eigenvalues are simple and taking $E = B - A$ gives required dependence between maximal eigenvalue of $A$ and $B$.

If $A$, $B$ are only nonnegative, then situation is much more complicated. If $A$ and $B$ are not diagonalizable, then there exists matrices $A$, $B$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_A$, $\lambda_B$ and $\|A-B\| \leq \epsilon$, such that $|\lambda_A - \lambda_B|\geq \eta$ for any $\eta, \epsilon \geq 0$.